# Hibernate: Double entries in ManyToMany Jointable

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

I have a ManyToMany Relation in my Domain Object and i want to user double entries in the JoinTable.
At the moment my code looks like this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="Purchase_BasicProduct", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="order_number")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id")})
private Set<BasicProduct> BasicProducts = new HashSet<BasicProduct>();
```

instead of the Set I want to use a List to enable double entries JoinTable. But when I use a list and I store the same entry the second time i get this error

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "purchase_basicproduct_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (order_number, id)=(703, 4) already exists.
```

is there a possibility to deactivate this unique constraint in the jointable. or would it be better to use a third column to store the amount of occurrences of an entry? and if this is the case, how can I store this third column and afterwards query for this?

Edit: for saving I use a generic Method. here is the code. T is substituted by an Object called Purchase. This stores all informations of an Purchase, and the Set with the ManyToMany association.

```
@Transactional
public void createEntity(T entity) throws DAOException {
    if(entity == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("entity mustn't be null!");
    }

    try{
        em.persist(entity);
    } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
        throw new DAOException("Can't update Entity!", e);
    } catch(TransactionRequiredException e) {
        throw new DAOException("Can't update Entity!", e);
    } catch(EntityExistsException e) {
        throw new DAOException("Can't update Entity!", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u show the code which you used to save

Comment: i have added the code to my post

Answer (score 0):

This is not about Hibernate. The error you're getting comes from the database: the couple order_number, id is a primary key and you cannot possibly insert multiple copies of it.

Comment: and is there any possibility to set up the database, that i do not have a primary key in this join table??

Comment: Of course there is. You can use SQL or the graphical administration tools of your DB, if you have the rights to do so. However, you should think twice before removing a primary key constraint, which is most probably there for a reason. Perhaps you don't really want duplicate entries in that join table, and you can design your data model differently.